# jquery .change and IE checkbox issues

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have had this problem before however the previous solution isn't working because there is an added complication with a function call. I have this code and it works fine in all browsers apart from IE.

```
 $('#HoldPaymentM').change(function(){$('#HoldPaymentW')[0].checked=$('#HoldPaymentM')[0].checked;CallCalc('calc');});
 $('#HoldPaymentW').change(function(){$('#HoldPaymentM')[0].checked=$('#HoldPaymentW')[0].checked;CallCalc('calc');});
```

If I change it to this it part works but keeps initialising the function call (which is not the desired behaviour

```
     $('#HoldPaymentW').bind($.browser.msie? 'propertychange': 'change', function() {
        $('#HoldPaymentM')[0].checked=$('#HoldPaymentW')[0].checked;CallCalc('calc');
        });

 $("#HoldPaymentM").bind($.browser.msie? 'propertychange': 'change', function() {
    $('#HoldPaymentM')[0].checked=$('#HoldPaymentW')[0].checked;CallCalc('calc');
    });
```

Could someone please help me discover the error of my ways? Changing "change|" to "click" doesn't work on this occasion.

Kind regards
Rachel

Comment: Why does using `click` not work?

Comment: not sure - have i got the syntax correct if I simply changed 'propertychange' to 'click'??

Comment: From what I understand it's a checkbox or radio button, why doesn't binding it to just the 'change' event work? $('#HoldPaymentW').bind('change', function() {
        $('#HoldPaymentM')[0].checked=$('#HoldPaymentW')[0].checked;CallCalc('calc');
        });

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work?

```
$('#HoldPaymentW').bind('change', function() {
        $('#HoldPaymentM')[0].checked=$('#HoldPaymentW')[0].checked;CallCalc('calc');

        });
```

Thses days I'm using `$('selector').on('change', function(e){/*do stuff*/});` all the time and it's working cross browser...

Comment: I'm narrowing it down to a conflict with this plugin i'm using - http://widowmaker.kiev.ua/checkbox/ - the code above does work but not when I initilise .checkbox from the above plugin :(